# Can't get new set of data into new column

Tags: python, excel, csv

Python & Coding Noobie here (been learning for 3 days), so please go easy on me!

I have a script to scrape a website and want to place the extracted data into two separate columns in a .csv sheet

The scrape script works well and gives me a list of dates; I'm now looking to put that list into 2 separate columns in a .csv sheet, however, the script I have made just takes the 2 lists and places them into a single column

I don't just want to duplicate the column because later (when I work out what I want to achieve) it will be a separate list - so it will be two separate columns with unique data

Thank you in advance!

---

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas

colnames = ['id']
data1 = pandas.read_excel('ch.xlsx', names=colnames, dtype=str)
names = data1.id.tolist()

def make_soup (url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
    return soupdata

chid = names

chdatasaved=""
chdatasaved2=""

for numb in chid:
    soup = make_soup ("https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/" + numb + "/filing-history")
    for record in soup.findAll("tr", limit=2):
        chdata=""
        for data in record.findAll("td", limit=1):
            chdata = chdata+","+data.text
        if len(chdata) !=0:
            chdatasaved = chdatasaved + chdata[0:]

filename = "date.csv"
f = open (filename, "w")
headers = "date, detail"
f.write (headers)
f.write (chdatasaved + chdatasaved + "\n")
f.close ()
```

---

nanojohn - your solution works, but now each character has its own row (see below) >

2

1

J

u

n

2

0

1

7

Will this be a problem within the scrape?

---

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas

colnames = ['id']
data1 = pandas.read_excel('ch.xlsx', names=colnames, dtype=str)
names = data1.id.tolist()

def make_soup (url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
    return soupdata

chid = names

chdatasaved = []

for numb in chid:
    soup = make_soup ("https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/" + numb + "/filing-history")
    for record in soup.findAll("tr", limit=2):
        chdata=""
        for data in record.findAll("td", limit=1):
            chdata = chdata+","+data.text
        if len(chdata) !=0:
            chdatasaved = chdatasaved.append(chdata[0:])

filename = "date.csv"
headers = "date, detail"
with open(filename,'w') as f:
    f.write(headers + '\n')
    for curDate in chdatasaved:
        f.write(curDate + "," + curDate + "\n")
```

Comment: Don't use pandas just to save it as a csv, there are better packages to handle csv, like package csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer**

You can keep the characters in the same row by doing:

```
with open(filename,'w') as f:
    f.write(headers + '\n')
    f.write(chdatasaved+ "," + chdatasaved+ "\n")
```

This works because `chdatasaved` is a string

**Previous answer**

You can easily loop through all the elements in your list to output as follows:

```
for curDate in chdatasaved:
    f.write(curDate + "," + curDate + "\n")
```

Note that you will also need to add the newline delimiter `"\n"` to the `f.write(headers)` line.

In general, it is better to read/write files with the `with` statement as follows, which will automatically handle the closing of the file:

```
with open(filename,'w') as f:
    f.write(headers + '\n')
    for curDate in chdatasaved:
        f.write(curDate + "," + curDate + "\n")
```

Comment: That does the job, but weirdly each character has it's own row (see my OP)?

Comment: Can you give me an example of what data is in `chdatasaved`? I was expecting it to be a list of dates such as: `[2015-06-01, 2015-06-02, ...]`

Comment: Hmmm - I think there is a problem with my scrape.  I get a lot of extra code and spaces (not sure where that is coming from - spaces not showing on this comment so have shown with  underscore) >  ',\n21 Jun 2017_________,\n13 Jun 2017__________,\n20 Jun 2017__________,\n09 May 2017__________,\n21 Jul 2017

Comment: Try checking the value of `chdata[0:]` for 1 item. You may need to amend this code to just get the date portion. Also, you should initialize `chdatasaved = []` as a list, and append elements by doing: `chdatasaved = chdatasaved.append(chdata[0:])`. Then my original answer should work (for loop on the `chdatasaved` list)

Comment: With the above I get the following error - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: You need to first initialize it as a list: `chdatasaved = []` as opposed to what you currently have, `chdatasaved = ""`

Comment: It's still showing that error - I have added the code with the implemented changes to my OP (at the bottom)

Comment: Apologies, the correct statement is just `chdatasaved.append(chdata[0:])`, you do not need to do assignment. You need to use the above rather than what I previously stated: `chdatasaved = chdatasaved.append(chdata[0:])`.

Comment: Thanks, nanojohn - I had to use chdatasaved.append(chdata[2:]), which seems to do the job ( [0:] place all on one column ).  Can you explain what that [0:] is please for the purpose of learning my end!

Comment: `chdata` contains a string, and so doing `[2:]` selects the substring starting from the 3rd position (0 indexing) to the end of the string. Doing `chdata[0:]` is equivalent to `chdata` since you would be selecting the "substring" starting at the begining